# printing values with matplotlib animation

Tags: animation, matplotlib, plot

so this is the crucial part of the code:

```
def animate(i):
    m=0
    k=0
    while(k<10):
        z=random.random()
        if(z<=0.9):
            m=m+1
        if(z>0.9):
            m=m-1
        k=k+1
    f=(m)
    j=(i*0.01)
    plot.set_data(j,f)
    plt.text(3,80,'Value y: '+m,fontsize=10)
```

it's an animation were a plot is showing a point with the value 'm' for y axe at each time 'i' for x axe, and I want to put a text were it shows the exact value of 'm' at the time 'i' with de plt.text, but it doesn't work, it doesn't appear in the plot... is there another function to do that? or is just me that I don't know how to implement this one? Thank you people you always help a lot!

Oh, and you if you know how to do that the plt.text shows the average value of m every 10i it would be perfect! Thank you again

[it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDY8y.png)

[and I want it to look somewhat like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RwAT.png)

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`m` is an integer. Therefore, change:

```
plt.text(3,80,'Value y: '+m,fontsize=10)
```

into:

```
plt.text(3, 80, 'Value y: {}'.format(m), fontsize=10)
```

[Animations in maptplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html) are not that simple. Best is to have a look at an [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/animate_decay.html).

Comment: wow thank you!it really works... but it gets stuck with the first value of m... it doesn't change with time i

Comment: Added some links for matplotlib animations.

Comment: You can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer if it solves your problem. This is just a partial solution but at least you get the desired result for the first point. ;)

Comment: done! sorry I'm new on this community I didn't even know I could do that hahaha